# Blogger java api reads only the last 25 posts

Tags: java, api, blogger

I have this code to read posts from a feed with the Blogger Java API

```
public static void printAllPosts(
        GoogleService myService, String blogId)
        throws ServiceException, IOException {
    // Request the feed
    URL feedUrl = new URL("http://www.blogger.com/feeds/" + blogId + "/posts/default");
    Feed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl, Feed.class);
    System.out.println("Number of posts: "+resultFeed.getEntries().size());
    // Print the results
    //System.out.println(resultFeed.getTitle().getPlainText());
    /*for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {
        Entry entry = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);
        System.out.println("\t" + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
    }*/
    System.out.println();
}
```

In this specific case, i'm just printing how many posts the library is fetching, and the output is always

```
Number of posts: 25
```

While i have 800 posts on my blog.

Why does it fetch only the latest 25 articles? What am i missing? How can i get it to read all posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this

```
URL feedUrl = new URL("http://www.blogger.com/feeds/" + blogId + "/posts/default");
```

with

```
URL feedUrl = new URL("http://www.blogger.com/feeds/" + blogId + "/posts/default?redirect=false&start-index=1&max-results=500");
```

The limit is 499 or 500 mostly
However,you can try putting 800 in the line,hope that works too :)